# Вопрос по ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть 2 взаимосвязанных инпута. Как сделать так, чтобы когда в первый начинал вводить слово, то снизу появлялось 2 таких же инпута, но уже пустые. И так далее.

Comment: у вас только React, или какая-то реализация Flux-архитектуры?

Comment: @Sergiks , только React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если навскидку, то получилось вот что:

```
var Inputs = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            numOfInputs: 1
        };
    },
    addInputs: function() {
        this.setState({
            numOfInputs: this.state.numOfInputs + 1
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var nodes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numOfInputs; i++) {
            if (i+1 === this.state.numOfInputs) {
                nodes.push(<Inputs key={i} onChange={this.addInputs}/>)
            } else {
                nodes.push(<Inputs key={i}/>);
            }
        }
        return <div>
            {nodes}
        </div>
    }
});

React.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxZqwQ

Comment: Если не любите JSX, то по ссылке в Codepen увидите чистый JS.